# ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode

Tags: python, unicode, sqlite

I'm trying to insert some database fields using  python to an SQLite DB. I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: operation parameter must be str
```

Below is my code.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("pass.db")
c = conn.cursor()

#Create table password
table_create_statement = "create table if not exists password(id integer primary key, site text, pass text);"
c.execute(table_create_statement)


#Promt user to input entry
sites = str(raw_input("Enter name of the sites: "))
password = str(raw_input("Enter password: "))

#SQL statement to insert the new entry
sql_statement = "insert into password values(?, ?, ?);",(None, sites, password)
c.execute((sql_statement))
connection.commit()
print("Password entered successfully")
```

Output:

```
Enter name of the sites: www.google.com
Enter password: abcd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pw.py", line 39, in <module>
    c.execute((sql_statement))
ValueError: operation parameter must be str or unicode
```

Comment: `sql_statement` is a `tuple`.... You want `sql_statement = "insert into password values(?, ?, ?);"` and `c.execute(sql_statement, (None, sites, password))` I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass in the sql statement and parameters as *separate arguments* to `execute()`. You are currently passing in a tuple.

Do this instead:

```
sql_statement = "insert into password values(?, ?, ?);"
c.execute(sql_statement, (None, sites, password))
```

Now `sql_statement` is a single string, and the parameters are passed in as a second, separate argument.

Note that `raw_input()` already returns a `str` object, no need to convert that to `str` again.